# How to know if geography point is within polygon

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I have these two fields lat-long
I made them to one field like this

```
alter table addresses add column geo_point geography;

UPDATE addresses SET geo_point = ST_POINT(latitude, longitude);
```

so now I want to get * from addresses if this point is in within polygon.

I tried this

```
select geo_point from addresses a 
WHERE ST_Contains(ST_GEOMFROMTEXT(('POLYGON( (-104.95768433837907 
39.71956203404201,-104.95768433837907 
39.75883237170433,-105.02291566162134 
39.75883237170433,-105.02291566162134 
39.71956203404201,-104.95768433837907 39.71956203404201))') ), 
a.geo_point);
```

some data

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DkYBm.png)

Comment: If nothing else, I think you're passing lat/long the wrong way around to `ST_POINT`. Beyond that, please add some *sample data* and expected results.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/15498/damien-the-unbeliever. I added a picture of data

Comment: We cannot copy and paste pictures of data into our own servers to set up test data. It's **far** better to present sample data as `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements as text (just including the columns of interest). Help others to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in your code. It should be:

```
ST_POINT(longitude, latitude)
```

because the docs for [ST_Point(X, Y)](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Point.html) say

> For geodetic coordinates, X is longitude and Y is latitude.